# Is there any way to retrieve real time data from sql server on GUI interface with wxpython?

Tags: user-interface, wxpython

I have a simple application about GUI with wxpython , I'd like to display real time value from database. Currently what I can do is to display the value from database , but I can not figure out how to make it REAL TIME , I mean when the data changed in database then I hope the data on this interface will synchronize with database. Hope it's clear. Anyone who can help on this ? Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Here I attached my code: Python 3.5 , Win 10

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import wx
import wx.adv
import wx.grid
import sys
import pyodbc
import time

bgcolor = (220,220,220)
class Mywin(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        super(Mywin, self).__init__(parent, title = title, size = (600,320))
        self.InitUI()

    def InitUI(self):
        nb = wx.Notebook(self)
        nb.AddPage(MyPanel3(nb), "Table")
        self.Centre()
        self.Show(True)

def retrieve_data_fromdb():
    # SQL Server configuration
    server = 'localhost'
    db = '***'
    user = 'sa'
    pwd = '******'

    src_db = pyodbc.connect(r'DRIVER={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};SERVER=' + server + ';DATABASE=' + db + ';UID=' + user + ';PWD=' + pwd)
    cur = src_db.cursor()

    select = 'select * from real_time_test'

    cur.execute(select)
    rows = cur.fetchone()
    wind_spd = rows[0]
    site_pwr = rows[1]
    acv_pr_setpnt = rows[2]
    park_pbl_cap = rows[3]
    tol_cur = rows[4]
    tol_non_prod = rows[5]
    data = []
    data.append(wind_spd)
    data.append(site_pwr)
    data.append(acv_pr_setpnt)
    data.append(park_pbl_cap)
    data.append(tol_cur)
    data.append(tol_non_prod)
    return data
    cur.commit()
    cur.close()
    src_db.close()

class MyPanel3(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(MyPanel3, self).__init__(parent)
        self.SetBackgroundColour(bgcolor)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_PAINT, self.OnPaint)

        title_NDC = wx.StaticText(self, -1, " Real time signals ", (30, 22))
        title_NDC.SetForegroundColour((0, 0, 255))
        wx.StaticText(self, -1, "1. Wind Speed", (35, 75))
        wx.StaticText(self, -1, "2. Site Power", (35, 95))
        wx.StaticText(self, -1, "Instant", (300, 45))

        wx.StaticText(self, -1, "m/s", (340, 75))
        wx.StaticText(self, -1, "kW", (340, 95))

        a = retrieve_data_fromdb()
        wind_spd_val = wx.StaticText(self, -1, a[0], (300, 75))
        wind_spd_val.SetForegroundColour((0, 0, 255))


    def OnPaint(self, event):
        pdc = wx.PaintDC(self)
        gc = wx.GCDC(pdc)
        gc.Clear()

        brush_rec = wx.Brush(bgcolor)
        gc.SetBrush(brush_rec)
        gc.SetPen(wx.Pen("black", 2))

        x1 = 20
        y1 = 30
        w1 = 500
        h1 = 180
        radius = 3
        gc.DrawRoundedRectangle(x1, y1, w1, h1, radius)


ex = wx.App()
Mywin(None,'My example')
ex.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 0):

An easy, if inefficient, way to achieve this is using a simple `Timer`.
Simply read the database once every x amount of time and update the screen.

Forgive the messy code but you'll get the idea.
Use the input box to update the value.
You'll have to fiddle with the database code, as I've used sqlite3, which is already on my box.

```
import wx
import sqlite3

class Frame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None)

    #Dummy database
        self.data = [['1111','Lots'],['2222','Fast'],['3333','Low']]
        self.db = sqlite3.connect("test1.db")
        self.cursor = self.db.cursor()
        self.cursor.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TEST(Id Text, Value Text)')
        self.cursor.execute("select * from TEST");
        test = self.cursor.fetchone()
        if not test:
            for i in self.data:
                result = self.db.execute("insert into Test (Id, Value) values (?,?)",(i[0],i[1]))
            self.db.commit()
            
        wx.StaticText(self, -1, "1. Wind Speed", (35, 75))
        wx.StaticText(self, -1, "2. Site Power", (35, 95))
        wx.StaticText(self, -1, "Instant", (300, 45))

        wx.StaticText(self, -1, "m/s", (340, 75))
        wx.StaticText(self, -1, "kW", (340, 95))
        self.wind = wx.TextCtrl(self, -1, pos=(35,200),style=wx.TE_RIGHT|wx.TE_PROCESS_ENTER)

        a = self.retrieve_data_fromdb()
        self.wind_spd_val = wx.StaticText(self, -1, a[1], (300, 75))

    #Bind the callbacks for the timer and the update function
        self.wind.Bind(wx.EVT_TEXT_ENTER, self.OnUpdate)
        self.dbtimer = wx.Timer(self)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_TIMER,self.OnTimer, self.dbtimer)
        self.dbtimer.Start(1000)

    def retrieve_data_fromdb(self):
        self.cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM Test where Id = ?",['2222'])
        a = self.cursor.fetchone()        
        return a

    def OnUpdate(self,event):
        self.cursor.execute("update Test set Value=? where Id=?" , (self.wind.GetValue(),'2222'))
        self.db.commit()

    def OnTimer(self,event):
        a = self.retrieve_data_fromdb()                
        self.wind_spd_val.SetLabel(a[1])
        print("Updated with "+str(a[1]))
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    frame = Frame()
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

[image]

Comment: Really really appreciated , after a bit modification on your code , it works well for me .

Comment: @Hoyand I'm glad it helped. Welcome to SO. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers